# Update query returning Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to execute the following query in Mysql:

```
UPDATE 
    jums_exam_marks_even_2019.student_total_marks_mphil
SET 
    year_percentage=round(((total+year_total)/250*100,1));
```

But I am getting an error

> Operand should contain 1 column(s)

What am I doing Wrong ?

Comment: Isn't there an extra set of parenthesis? I'm assuming you want to call `round((...),1)`, while your code shows `round(((...),1))`

Comment: Update jums_exam_marks_even_2019.student_total_marks_mphil set year_percentage=round( ((total+year_total)/(fm+year_full_marks)*100,1) );

Comment: It still has too many parenthesis, try `round((total+year_total)/(fm+year_full_marks)*100, 1)` please :)

Comment: extra parenthesis you are using there remove it.